# Serve Vue js application on docker

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm

I want to dockerize my vueJs application. On my local machine I am able to install and serve my application on localhost by running command ***npm install*** and ***npm run serve***.

I want to create a docker image so I wrote a dockerfile. My dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM Image_Name

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "serve"]
```

But I am not able to run my docker image with docker run command. Any idea what I am doing wrong.

After running the run command-

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    completion, config, create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate,
    dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit, explore, get, help,
    help-search, hook, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,
    list, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
    prefix, profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart,
    root, run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h     quick help on <command>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /root/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.2.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Comment: Did you build the container before running using `docker build` ?

Comment: Please post your complete `docker run` command and its output so we can see what's going on.

Comment: @fxgx yes, i build the container before using it.

Comment: provide package*.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to execute 
`npm run serve`
 you should put 
`CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]` in your Dockerfile. 
You are missing the `run` part.

Comment: Thanks, stupid me , this was bugging me from past 1 hour.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)
The error is trying to tell you that you misused the `npm` command.
Good luck for your project!